# ONLY Show Customer Group Pricing

Tags: customer-group, group-price, template-hints

Im developing a B2B Store.  I have a number of customers which have special prices for SOME products.  At the moment I have set them up under 'Customer Groups' and applied group prices to the products.  On the front end, when the customer is logged in, their special price is shown alongside the standard price which has greyed out/strikethrough style.

I want my site to HIDE the standard price when there is a group price available instead of strikethrough/grey out, but still show standard price where there is no alternative group price.  Does anyone know of an extension for this or will this need to be hand coded?

I'm only looking to HIDE normal price when there is a group price available.

I'm using standard Madison Island template.

Comment: You will have to modify the price template file.. Good luck with that :)

Comment: you should debug prie.phtml @GadgetManJay

Comment: I can't find a file called 'prie.phtml'.  Do you mean 'price.html?  Can you provide more information, step by step, etc, please?

Comment: I apologize if my comment came out rude. Here I have a solution for you.

Comment: Keyur Shah, I believe your assessment of this is flawed.  This question is VERY specific!!  It specifically asks how to remove the 'original/old/base price' content from the front end so as to only show the relevant price available.  And a suitable solution has been applied below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your theme's `catalog/product/price.phtml` template. In your case, that is the `rwd` theme.

> I would advise you to do this on a separate theme and apply the changes there, but it might be too complicated on your case... Anyhow, just keep a backup of the original template file. So you can revert it back if you break something.

1. Open the template file `app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\price.phtml`.
2. Find all `<p>` tags that has a class `old-price`
3. Delete that and everything inside it.

There's about 5 `<p>` tags that you're going to delete.

Comment: delete <p> tag is not solution it may create issue

Comment: Will this not remove the base price completely from ALL views?

Comment: @KeyurShah Hiding the old price is not a good idea overall, but it is what he/she wants.

Comment: @GadgetManJay This will only hide the old price (discounted price) and not the base price. Yes, all views use this template for price processing, unless a third party extension rewrites it.

Comment: What sort of issues may this cause?  My store is B2B so all price is hidden until user is logged in anyway.  Then we have base price to most users, but our bigger customers get special price on SOME products.  I have removed the <p old-price> sections (there were 5), and this is now only showing base price OR group price which is awesome.  BUT can you tell me what issues may occur by doing this?

Comment: The thing is, it wouldn't check how it got an `old-price`. Magento has several discount features (group price, catalog price rules, special prices, third party extension modifying price). It will not show the "standard price" for any of these discounts. If that's ok with you then it should be fine.

Comment: Basically, the customer won't know if he/she got a discount of any type. Most stores actually want to let their customer know that they have a discount.

Comment: Of course.  My clients customer base is B2B customers only.  All customers are credit account and there is no on-site registration/guest checkout.  They are only interested in the price they pay and any promotional events are marketed, rarely special offers, etc sot his solution is perfect for them, thank you.  As soon as I get some 'rep' ill upvote this.